# If Earth had rings, how long would it take for the rings to loose orbit?

Tags: orbit, gravity, earth, planetary-ring

If Earth had rings, how long would it take for the rings to loose orbit? One of the answers in this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/281828/if-earth-had-rings said we did at one time is it possible? [image]

Comment: I doubt you'll find a good estimate, but if you are interested in this subject I'd suggest search for "stability of ring systems" on the web and some papers ought to crop up.

Comment: Too add to what @StephenG said.  Ring systems like Saturn's are probably stable for several to many millions of years.  A ring system on a planet subject to the tides Earth is subject to from the Moon and Sun would probably have a shorter life-span.   I wouldn't want to guess how much shorter, but possibly an order of magnitude or two shorter, maybe more.

Comment: From the (very) little I understand about this I gather that the mass and makeup of the rings has more significance in determining stability than might seem likely at first thought.